# Showing $n!=\Theta \sqrt n ({n\over e})^n$ using integration.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, combinatorics

Show $n!=\Theta (\sqrt n ({n\over e})^n)$ integration. Where $f=\Theta (g)$ means, by the definition we were given in class, that $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$. A question prior to it I showed that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} {n\choose i}\le ({en\over k})^k$ and other forms of this inequality, and I feel like it should be used, but I am not sure how. Is it possible to show that without the Stirling formula? After all, it is not exactly what I am asked for.

Comment: You forgot a $\sqrt{n}$ in Stirling's... and assuming Stirling's formula is a stronger statement than what you are asked to prove. (As it's basically "the same, with the exact constant")

Comment: I guess I have been remiss in understanding the area of information I was expected to use. Thank you for noting that.